# Extbase: generate translated entries from frontend input

Tags: typo3, extbase

Problem: Extbase Extension with a frontend form which generates new entries in two different languages. All text fields in the frontend form exists in the two languages. The entries are merged to two objects, $origin and $translation. My problem is to persist both entries like real translations, they should be connected in the same way like a translation in the backend.

In TYPO3 vs. 10 this was accomplished with a small service from here: https://gist.github.com/witrin/764bc856decf26c5e784

But in vs. 11 of TYPO3 this service does not work anymore. The entries are not linked via parent_id and translations do not inherit from the original language any more.

Any ideas what could have changed in vs. 11?

Thanks.